# MID + LEN function in Excel to extract letters + number with an inconsistent pattern

Tags: excel, function, excel-formula

I have a column that has information on customers. I want to extract just the CS number from the each cell. Below are examples of what some of the cells look like.

```
John Smith/CS41628644/555-555-5555

johnsmith,cs41923409,5555555555

John Smith - CS41821976 - 555-555-5555

Smith CS21893002 PN 5555555555

John Smith 555-555-5555 (CS17838618)
```

As you can see, they don't follow a consistent pattern in terms of where the CS# falls within the cell, or what precedes or follows it. To make matters more complicated, there are a few instances where the number is 7 digits long, instead of 8 (but the vast majority are 8).

Here's what I'd like to do. Write a function that says: "When 'CS' (not case sensitive) is found, extract all the consecutive integers that follow until a non-integer is found, then stop."

Does that make sense? Is there a better way to do this? My current formula is actually missing some of the 8 digit CS numbers, so my thinking is I should start from scratch. Here is what I have just for more context.

```
=LOOKUP(2,1/(MMULT(0+(ISNUMBER(-MID(" "&N252,ROW(INDIRECT("1:"&LEN(N252)))+{0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9},1))+0={0,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,0}),{1;1;1;1;1;1;1;1;1;1})=10),MID(N252,ROW( INDIRECT("1:"&LEN(N252))),8))
```

Comment: I can't speak on how to do this in Excel, but if you can use a regular expression, you can match like `[cC][sC](\d+)`.  Not an answer, but gives you something to Google.

Comment: @Vityata - any suggestions?

Comment: Could we safely say that *if* the number after "CS" is 8 characters, the last character is numeric? If the 8th number after "CS" is **not** numeric, CS is 7 characters?

Comment: @BruceWayne yes that is correct. If the CS is 8 numbers, the 8th digit is numeric. If not the CS is 7 numbers

Answer (score 3):

Try this small User Defined Function:

```
Public Function GetCS(r As Range) As String
    Dim L As Long, v As String, L2 As Long, CH As String
    Dim i As Long

    GetCS = ""
    v = UCase(r.Text)
    L = InStr(1, v, "CS")
    L2 = Len(v)
    If L2 = 0 Or L = 0 Or L = L2 - 1 Then Exit Function

    For i = L + 2 To L2
        CH = Mid(v, i, 1)
        If IsNumeric(CH) Then
            GetCS = GetCS & CH
        Else
            Exit Function
        End If
    Next i
End Function
```

[image]

User Defined Functions (UDFs) are very easy to install and use:

1. ALT-F11  brings up the VBE window
2. ALT-I
   ALT-M opens a fresh module
3. paste the stuff in and close the VBE window

If you save the workbook, the UDF will be saved with it.
If you are using a version of Excel later then 2003, you must save
the file as .xlsm rather than .xlsx

To remove the UDF:

1. bring up the VBE window as above
2. clear the code out
3. close the VBE window

To use the UDF from Excel:

=myfunction(A1)

To learn more about macros in general, see:

http://www.mvps.org/dmcritchie/excel/getstarted.htm

and

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee814735(v=office.14).aspx

and for specifics on UDFs, see:

http://www.cpearson.com/excel/WritingFunctionsInVBA.aspx

**Macros must be enabled for this to work!**

Answer (score 1):

Here is a formula that will return the CS number from column A or B or an error value if there is nothing.  The CS number can be any length.

```
=IFERROR(MID(A1,SEARCH("cs",A1),MATCH(FALSE,ISNUMBER(-MID(A1,SEARCH("cs",A1)+2,seq)),0)+1),MID(B1,SEARCH("cs",B1),MATCH(FALSE,ISNUMBER(-MID(B1,SEARCH("cs",B1)+2,seq)),0)+1))
```

The formula is an **Array formula** and must be confirmed by holding down <kbd>ctrl</kbd> `+` <kbd>shift</kbd> while hitting <kbd>enter</kbd>

`seq` is a *Named Formula**

```
seq  Refers To:  =ROW(INDEX(Sheet1!$1:$65535,1,1):INDEX(Sheet1!$1:$65535,255,1))
```

[image]

If you are interested in a User Defined Function (UDF), here is one that uses

- regular expression to find the first `cs` in the string.
- then return the `cs` plus all of the digits following
- It can accept multiple, comma separated arguments so as to be able to check a second (or third) cell if the first cell is empty.
- It returns an error message if there is no `cs` number, but this can be easily changed in the code.

So both of the following are valid:

```
=CSNum(A1)
=CSNum(A1,B1)
```

**Regular Module**

```
Option Explicit
Function CSNum(ParamArray S() As Variant) As Variant
    Dim RE As Object, MC As Object
    Dim V As Variant

Set RE = CreateObject("vbscript.regexp")
With RE
    .ignorecase = True
    .Pattern = "cs\d+"
        For Each V In S
            If .test(V) = True Then
                Set MC = .Execute(V)
                CSNum = MC(0)
                Exit Function
            End If
        Next V
End With

If CSNum = "" Then CSNum = CVErr(xlErrValue)

End Function
```

Answer (score 0):

This should work, if you're interested in a formula:

```
=IF(ISERR(NUMBERVALUE(MID(A1,SEARCH("CS",A1)+9,1))),MID(A1,SEARCH("CS",A1),9),MID(A1,SEARCH("CS",A1),10))
```

A little convoluted, but basically it sees if it can turn the 9th character after "CS" into a number. If not, return "CS"+9 characters total, otherwise "CS"+10.

Comment: how can I add in a clause to look in Column B and run the same thing if this does not return anything when looking in A?

Comment: any ideas? I tried nesting in an IF statement but no luck. The issue is that for a few cases, the CS number appears in column B, so I want to run the same function you wrote in the case that nothing is yielded from looking in column A

Comment: =IF([formula above]="",[formula above, but swithc to col. b])`?

Comment: I wrote =IF([formula above] = "#VALUE!", [formula above with B], [formula above] but still not getting it to yield the CS number. Does it have to do with saying it equals "#VALUE!" -- I tried "" as well to no avail

Comment: I can send you the line item example if that is helpful. thank you for your continued help

Comment: Column A contains John Smith - 555-555-5555 while Column B contains 
John Smith - 555-555-5555 (phone) CS17284329. Thus, the formula when looking in column A returns #VALUE!. I want it to look in Column B and find the CS #     '=IF(IF(ISERR(NUMBERVALUE(MID(K325,SEARCH("CS",K325)+9,1))),MID(K325,SEARCH("CS",K325),9),MID(K325,SEARCH("CS",K325),10)), "#VALUE!", IF(ISERR(NUMBERVALUE(MID(O325,SEARCH("CS", O325)+9,1))),MID(O325,SEARCH("CS",O325),9),MID(O325,SEARCH("CS",O325),10)), IF(ISERR(NUMBERVALUE(MID(K325,SEARCH("CS",K325)+9,1))),MID(K325,SEARCH("CS",K325),9),MID(K325,SEARCH("CS",K325),10)))